# Obtaining up-to-date list of US ZIP Codes with Latitude and Longitude Geocodes?

Tags: data, geocoding, united-states, centroids

*NOTE: This began as a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4682194/166258), which has subsequently been closed.  I also noticed a similar question about [Most Up-To-Date Source for US Zip Code Boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/most-up-to-date-source-for-us-zip-code-boundaries), but I believe this question is different in that I'm not looking for* ***boundaries*** *as much as I'm looking for* ***coordinates***. *Sorry for new newbie question.  I'm not sure where to look to find reliable and up-to-date data.*

We have a table in our database that has latitude and longitude geocode coordinates paired with US zip codes.  A sample of the data looks like this:

```
Zip   State  Latitude    Longitude
30000   GA  33.906553   -84.206311
30001   GA  33.810659   -84.607964
30002   GA  33.77429    -84.260712
30003   GA  33.906553   -84.206311
30004   GA  34.113832   -84.294578
30005   GA  34.079927   -84.221166
30006   GA  33.906553   -84.206311
30007   GA  33.968777   -84.43282
30008   GA  33.902022   -84.580318
30009   GA  33.906553   -84.206311
```

The problem is that our data hasn't been updated for a few years.

Where can I obtain (for free or for purchase) updated data for this table?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

ZIP codes are a habitually abused geography.  It's understandable that people want to use them because they are so visible and well-known but they aren't well suited to any use outside the USPS.  ZIP codes aren't associated with polygons, they are associated with carrier routes and the USPS doesn't like to share those.  Some ZIP codes are points e.g.  a ZIP code may be associated with a post office, a university or a large corporate complex.  They are used to deliver mail.

The Census Bureau creates ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTA) based on their address database.  If it's appropriate to your work you could try taking the centroid of the ZCTAs.  [ZCTA Geography from the 2010 Census](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=ZIP+Code+Tabulation+Areas) is available on the Census Bureau website.

See also: [ZIP Code Geography and Mapping](http://www.sdc.ucsb.edu/guides/zip_codes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your well-explained answer.  It's clear that ZIP codes are abused, but that's what the business is using so I don't have much choice for this particular application, unfortunately.  I'll pay attention to the census data for future updates.

Comment: ZCTA for 2010 TIGER are now available ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/ZCTA5/2010/

Comment: @Sean, but even the Census says the ZCTA don't match the USPS true boundary, it is just the tabulation block they use. Yes, it is the most recent free source, but you need to take that caveat into consideration.

Comment: @D.E.Wright, yes, that's why they're called ZIP Code Tabulation Areas. There is no USPS true boundary.

Comment: Dead link in the original answer. Looks like the current URL is https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/zcta_rel_download.html.

Comment: very simple API for this already https://boundaries-io.com  you can create complex queries as well.

Answer (score 21):

Try this: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

It is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License.  They even have zip codes of various other countries around the world.

Comment: I checked a few zip codes that were added last year, e.g. 32461, and the US.zip database includes them, so this resource seems to be up to date.

Comment: These are likely ZCTA (see http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes-sources.html)

Comment: They are not only ZCTA. There are 41466 zip codes, including ones that are not ZCTA (for example, 80201).

Comment: This looks awesome. Thanks so much @teesid!

Answer (score 7):

One thing not mentioned, but **very important**, is that the Census data is not a complete list of all ZIP Codes (ZCTAs). It is a list of ZCTAs that have a population, so PO Boxes, etc. are not in the data. There are about 42,000 ZIP Codes and about 33,000 ZCTAs.

For a complete file and true accuracy, you'll want to get a commercial product such as what Puddleglum mentioned.

One last thing not mentioned: **all coordinates are not created equal!** We've seen some very popular databases off by over 20 miles in the congested Northeast! Ask vendors to give you a sample of data in *your area* (not their standard demo file) and use a free product such as ArcGIS Explorer to verify (you can download a ZIP Code boundaries layer from their web server, ArcGIS Online, for free!)

Comment: For many purposes (like weather APIs) this is okay.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt

Comment: That looks exactly like what I would need, but the data is 10 years old.  I suppose I may have to wait until the 2010 Census data is processed.

Comment: this is only 8 years old :(   http://www2.census.gov/cgi-bin/shapefiles/national-files

Comment: Both of links above are not found now.

Comment: http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

Comment: answer needs editing, links are gone

Comment: Please see my answer for the up-to-date files.

Comment: The problem with this version of data is it does not matches with the google maps (e.g. in case of roads)

Comment: @SIslam this data is not intended to match google maps, it is not part of the question. you will have to do some re-projection work to get the best fit for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The USPS offers this service...they *should* be the authority.  (Although even *their* data seems to be compiled from a variety of sources, including but not limited to US Census...)

http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

They just provide a latlong (presumably a centroid) but one could always (ab)use the google Earth API to at least get a bounding box for each,

e.g.

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=13357&output=xml

Comment: The unitedstateszipcodes.org data set is third-party, not affiliated with the USPS in any way. That's why "their data" comes from multiple sources.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [CivicSpace US ZIP Code Database](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2010/12/11/geocode-zip-codes/).  It's also available as a [package in R](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/cran-zipcode/), if you happen to [use R](http://cran.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You can now get the updated 2010 data directly from the Census Bureau itself. This source has the coordinates of each ZCTA as well as some other information. It should be free/public domain.

http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2010.html

> The ZIP Code Tabulation Area file contains data for all ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs) in the 50 states, the District of Columbia and Puerto Rico as of the January 1, 2010. The file is ASCII text, one line per record.

Direct link to the file: http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/docs/gazetteer/Gaz_zcta_national.zip

Answer (score 2):

Current data from the USPS can be had for a relatively low price, between $100 and $200.  There are a number of vendors that are non-exclusive licensees of USPS data.  A list is available here, http://ribbs.usps.gov/files/dpv/CERTIFIED_LICENSEES.TXT.
DPV, Delivery Point Validation, certifies an address as deliverable, versus an address which falls within a deliverable street and address range.  If an address is deliverable, a ZIP+4 is assigned as opposed to just a 5 digit ZIP.  Some of the licensees of the data match the street and address range from the USPS with an external street centerline file to provide a geographic point representing a ZIP+4.  This level of detail can be generalized back to the ZIP code and derive a ZIP point.
Two products come to mind, ZP4 from Semaphore and ZIP*Data from Melissa Data.
I think that the TIGER data from 2000 will be lacking, particularily for any new ZIP codes since then.
All of the 2010 TIGER should be available by April. They are rolling states out weekly.

Comment: 2010 Tiger shapefile release schedule and downloads: http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html

Comment: its free, and does not cost anything.

Answer (score 2):

The US Census Bureau has Gazetteer files:

http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer.html

For each year, there is an accompanying webpage. Select "Zip Code Tabulation Areas", and you will see a download link for a file. For example, the 2013 file is named "2013_Gaz_zcta_national.zip", which unzips into a tab-separated file. The schema for this file contains a zip code and a latitude, longitude pair, presumably the centroid of the zip code.

Comment: How is this answer different from: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63076/442?

Comment: That answer is relevant to 2010 only.

Comment: this is not a good source. for example 94101 (down town San Francisco) does not appear in the 2015 file

Comment: @Gus 94101 is not a valid zip code [according to the USPS](https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=94101&zip=).

Comment: @vaindil and yet google seems to know where it is..  https://www.google.com/search?q=94101+zip+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Gus Google may know that, but the USPS is the official source for zip code information. If the USPS doesn't have it, then it's not official.

Comment: @Vaindil don't have time to research it, but possibly it's decommissioned? If so it still implies a geo-location.

Answer (score 2):

The U.S. Gazetteer Files has a simple file for 5-digit US ZIP codes in their ZIP Code Tabulation Areas file. It has the following columns:

```
Column 1    GEOID       Five digit ZIP Code Tabulation Area Census Code
Column 2    ALAND       Land Area (square meters)
Column 3    AWATER      Water Area (square meters)
Column 4    ALAND_SQMI  Land Area (square miles)
Column 5    AWATER_SQMI Water Area (square miles)
Column 6    INTPTLAT    Latitude (decimal degrees)
Column 7    INTPTLONG   Longitude (decimal degrees)
```

The latest gazetteer file can be found at the bottom of https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/geo/gazetteer-files.html under "ZIP Code Tabulation Areas".

Answer (score 1):

**[Edited 8/3/2015]** Update - the free ZIP Code database I mentioned below has now moved to [softwaretools.com](https://softwaretools.com)

As others have mentioned, census zcta is slightly different than a ZIP Code (quickly illustrated [here](http://greatdata.com/resources)). Furthermore, the coordinates can be population center points (where people live) or geometric center points (mathmatical calc - often fall in forestry land, large lakes, etc). For geometric, you can get it for free [here](http://greatdata.com/free-zip-code-database). For population-based, you'll need a commercial grade ZIP Code database like [this one](http://greatdata.com/zip-code-data/usa).

fyi - I'm a developer for greatdata.com

Comment: If you work for a vendor and are referencing your own products, you should disclose that in your answer, as described in the [community FAQ regarding self promotion](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).