# From where can I download WKT files for US zip codes?

Tags: well-known-text, zip-codes

From where can I download WKT files for US zip codes?

I need to plot zip code boundary on a map using OpenLayers,

Comment: It is unlikely anybody would store spatial data in such an inefficient format, but of course once you have obtained the data in *some* format you can easily convert it to WKT. Perhaps, then, you will be satisfied with the answers at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/where-can-i-obtain-an-up-to-date-list-of-us-zip-codes-with-latitude-and-longitud, which show where to find Zip code spatial data.