# Geocode US ZIP codes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server, geocoding

I have a list of zip codes (nearly thousands) which I want to show in qgis. After researching I found that I need to geocode them first into Lat/Long then I can use them to create a layer for qgis.

I have the zip codes in an excel file and I have imported it in sql server 2008.

Here is the table :

```
Zip
90001
90002
90003
90004
```

Is there a plugin or an easier way to show these zip's in QGIS?

Comment: Could you post one entry in your table to show what it looks like? Is there any spatial information included (eg. coordinates)?

Comment: @Martin Edited the post.

Comment: So your table does *not* include any spatial information?

Comment: yes it is plan zip codes which I want to convert to polygon which then I can plot it in qgis. But how can I do this? Sorry I am a newbie in shapefiles.

Comment: @snyder I may be wrong but you can download the shape file contains US zip codes (Please check here http://spotfirecommunity.tibco.com/community/forums/p/2567/7788.aspx) then convert shape file to sql format using shptosql converter ...may be helpful for you

Comment: Zip codes themselves (for whatever country you are in) *does not contain any spatial information* (eg. where in the world they are located), same as you can't just magically display a set of city names on a map. You need information about each zone's extent expressed as coordinates/vertexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could download the US Census [Zip Code Tabulation Areas](http://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html).  Then join your Zip Code (numbers) to the ZCTA's and ultimately give you the spatial polygons that *generally* represent the Zip Code boundaries.  While not a 1-to-1 match (because the US Postal Service does not publish their zip code boundaries), it should get you close.

See also:

- [Most Up-To-Date Source for US Zip Code Boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/most-up-to-date-source-for-us-zip-code-boundaries)
- [Where can I obtain an up-to-date list of US ZIP Codes with Latitude and Longitude Geocodes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/where-can-i-obtain-an-up-to-date-list-of-us-zip-codes-with-latitude-and-longitud)

Answer (score 2):

Please check out following links might be helpful for you to plot & see us zipcodes in QGIS.

1- http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/geonamesorg-postal-code-files-us-zip-code-geolocations (download points data and use Delimited Text Layer plugin to load csv or tsv in QGIS.)

2- http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/usa/census/zip_poly.zip (Polygon Data)

i hope it will help.