# Postcodes mapping

Tags: qgis, postal-code

I am new to GIS. 
I have a list of postcodes and I have to make a map, basically to show distance from a specific area. Concentric ring pull type of map. 
I don't know how to get my postcodes into a format where I can add them to a GIS map. I am using QGIS.

Comment: You need to define coordinates for each postcode. There have been questions before where the answers show how you can do that and why it is possibly a bad idea. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/where-can-i-obtain-an-up-to-date-list-of-us-zip-codes-with-latitude-and-longitud

Comment: just use this API for UK boundaries...it supports postal units,sectors, and districts.. www.boundaries-io.com

Answer (score 6):

You can download Code-point Open from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html to get a coordinate of each postcode unit that you can join to your existing postcodes.

Comment: OpenNames will be replacing the CodePoint Open dataset https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html for reference see > http://chris-osm.blogspot.com/2015/06/new-postcode-layer.html Now sub-metre accuracy but in other areas there are issues.