# QGIS-- Find zipcode boundaries bisected by city boundaries

Tags: qgis, zip-codes, intersect

I've tried the intersect function but that also returns small zipcodes entirely within a city. Ideally, I just need zipcodes that extend beyond city lines.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you are looking for is select by location under: **Vector => Research Tools => Select by Location** with settings as in the image below.

[image]

The zipcode layers goes in the first dropdown and the city layer in the second dropdown. Check **include features that overlap/cross the selection** features. And you should get only intersecting features as below:

[image]

Comment: I have QGIS 2.18 and the window looks completely different. The issue I have is I know multiple zipcodes are in multiple cities and vice versa. Is there a way to do a many to many join?

Comment: I used QGIS 2.14.14 for the screen shots... And I think the discussion on this link may be  helpful to resolving you question:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53918/determining-which-us-zipcodes-map-to-more-than-one-state-or-more-than-one-city