# Getting a list of zip codes with its adjacent zip codes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, united-states

I need a list in the form of adjacency list that contains all zip codes in the United States that each has a list of adjacent zip codes. I tried searching for it on the internet. Many of them only provide a list, but none of them had a list showing the adjacent list of zip codes. How do I find something like that?

The closest thing I found is a list of counties and their adjacent counties. There are several websites that I believe that they have the information but they are using it for applets like this website, http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm

If no data is available, could I use the counties list to generate the said list?

EDIT: OP here, I was new to the whole GIS system. I don't know which software to use. I decided to try ArcGIS trial. I downloaded ArcGIS and that .lpk file. But I have no idea how to properly load .lpk in a python script and run PolygonNeighbors_analysis function. ArcPy Documentation and Google are not giving me a clear answer. Can anyone show me how to load .lpk package and use the function? Thanks

EDIT2: I think I should have mentioned that I want that list in a simple .txt file. I think I could do this with ArcPY to collect all zip codes and their neighbors, then store it in the .txt file. My current obstacle to this is that I have no idea how to load .lpk file to ArcPY.

EDIT3: I got it to work! By following what Barrett described, I got a raw .txt file of zip codes and their neighbors. I cleaned it up with my small program. It looks good. Thanks for help!

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate the GIS software and version you have available to "generate the said list", please?

Comment: See my updated answer - you do not need to use ArcPy. Open ArcToolbox, Find & Open the Tool, then Drag the layer into the tool.

Comment: Can you make this zip code adjacency file available? thank you

Comment: Do you mind sharing your txt file of zip codes with their neighbor zip codes? Thanks

Comment: Hi Tom, can you please share the .txt file.

Answer (score 8):

Get a zip-code boundary layer and run [Polygon Neighbors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000045000000). Review [How Polygon Neighbors Works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000047000000) and [Up-To-Date Zip-Code Boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/most-up-to-date-source-for-us-zip-code-boundaries)

Picture below might be different than your ArcMap looks, but the buttons and procedure should be the same.

[image: ArcToolbox Example]

Perhaps this is an open-source solution. I have not tested or used this solution which seems to require GRASS 6+ : from the [GRASS users mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2005-May/028972.html)

> Daniel Isenegger wrote:
>
> > Hi,
> >     i work with grass 5.7 having the attribute data in postgres-DB.
> >
> > in a polygon-shapefile containing several hundred of polygons i want to 
> >     analyze for each polygon which neighboring polygons it has. Conceptually 
> >     i see there 2 cases:
> >     1) neighboring polygons sharing a common boundary with the current 
> >     polygon: these polygons should be selectable by identifying the 
> >     identifiers of the border-lines of the current polygon and search over 
> >     all border-lines of all polygons for those identifiers.
> >     here my question is: how to identify the identifiers of all border-lines 
> >     of a polygon?
>
> [v.category](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.category.html) layer=2 type=boundary to assign cat to boundaries
>
> [v.to.db](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.to.db.html) option=sides -p

Comment: That's a solution Barret, however the OP has not indicated the software yet. I would recommend if you're going to assume software that you assume *open source* as if they don't have it they can install it without cost. It is a nice, neat solution for users of ArcGIS though.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson good point. If this is a one-off calculation the OP could consider installing a [trial version of ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial)

Comment: Point Taken, Michael.

Comment: ESRI offers free ZIp Code Boundaries, http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24. You need ArcGIS to use this layer.