# Using excel info to create thematic map

Tags: excel, mxd, zip-codes, thematic-map

So, I have an excel spreadsheet with information regarding people within a certain zip code. I basically need to make a map that shows the amount of people within each zip code either using dots or representative colors. How should I do this? The spreadsheet is set up with columns of name, email, and zip codes.

Comment: Zipcode's are not polygons or points https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/sources-for-us-zip-code-boundaries

Comment: Depending on the version of Excel that you have you could use the 3D Maps option under the Insert ribbon.