# Online source of polygon nodes for individual newly created zipcodes

Tags: shapefile, polygon, zip-codes, nodes

When a new zipcode is created it would be very convenient to obtain its polygon nodes from an online source, without having to download a national dataset. Does an online web-page or web-API exist, where you can provide a zipcode as a search-term and get back its shapefile nodes expressed as a series of latitude/longitude pairs?

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/sources-for-us-zip-code-boundaries

Comment: Thanks, Not the one-zipcode-at-a-time source I am hoping to find.  We'll get a dataset of 700 zipcodes, say, and only two of them are ones we don't already have. Hoping to find a way to fetch this data for a supplied zipcode without having to download and import a new file on a monthly basis.